# Execute code only on initial login AzureAD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am using AzureAD for authentication in an ASP .Net Core application, and all is functioning as expected.  Within my _LoginPartial, I want to execute something only on the first time the user logs in, rather than repeating it every time _LoginPartial is executed (on each page load).  Also, what's the best way to add code to execute at the login, there's no code-behind for the _LoginPartial.  I want to set some session variables at first login of user.  Should I create another view component to do this?

Current _LoginPartial:

```
@using System.Security.Principal

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ViewBag.UserId = User.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")?.Value;
            ViewBag.Name = User.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Type == "name")?.Value;
            ViewBag.Username = User.Identity.Name;
            ViewBag.TenantId = User.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid")?.Value;

         

            <li>
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("UserStatistics", new { StatDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")})
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="nav-item profile">
                <span class="navbar-text text-dark" style="color:white !important;">Welcome @ViewBag.Name!</span>
                </li>

            <li class="nav-item profile">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
            </li>
                }
                else
                {
                   
            <li class="nav-item" style="padding-left:10px;padding-top:0">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

Comment: Hi @George,`_LoginPartial` exists in your _Layout.cshtml. It would be executed  every time by default.Just add the session variables in the `_LoginPartial`.

Comment: How do I set session variables inside _LoginPartial?  And I want something to only execute once when they login, not every time _Layout loads _LoginPartial.

Comment: Did you get a chance you look into `void Session_Start` method in the class defined in Global.asax.cs which calls only at the session start

Comment: Hi @GeorgeHarris does the above comments helps you to resolve your issue or you still looking for any help on this?

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer for this